# Assign UITableViewController custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make my UITableViewController a custom class of "View Controller" But the option is greyed out, and every time I enter it, it juts goes back to normal.

I've tried creating a new project, using old ones etc. No luck, Any ideas? Am I missing something extremely obvious here?

Works fine with normal view controllers etc.

EDIT SOLVED: I just created a new View Controller with UITableViewController as it's class and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can explain it?

I'm unable to make my UITableViewController's custom class equal to my ViewController. The option is greyed out. The Default is UITableViewController.

I'm trying to link it to my ViewController. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

YourTableViewController must be inherit UITableViewController , not UIViewController.

Comment: But it does? @interface ViewController : UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it is in the same folder through Finder! It might look like it from XCode but in Finder it may be different!

Comment: Just had a look, it's all in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new View Controller with UITableViewController as it's class and it worked fine.